# Logging after file created miss several rows

Tags: laravel, logging

I worte a trait to log something,but when use it to log first time(file not exists), some log contents looks like missing.

Tried to debug several times,not solved.

helper trait

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

trait OutToLog
{
    public function outLogTo(string $channel, string $logContents)
    {
        Log::channel($channel)->info($logContents);
    }
}
```

expected log

```
[2019-10-20 19:19:42] INFO: status=200;
request=test_request;
response=test_response;

[2019-10-20 19:19:42] INFO: status=300;
request=test_request;
response=test_response;

[2019-10-20 19:19:42] INFO: Test notify service with exception.
```

real got log

```
[2019-10-20 19:19:42] INFO: Test notify service with exception.  
=test_response;
```

After first test,second test and after that doesn't have same problem.
Really don't get it why.

This is called like shown as below:

```
    private function resultLog(array $result): void
    {
        if ($result['status'] === 200) {
            doSomething...
        }

        $resultLog = "status=" . $result['status'] . $resultRequest . ";\n" .$resultResponse. "\n";
        $this->outLogTo('channel_name', $resultLog);
    }
```

And this is called like

```
    try {
        $this->resultLog($result);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->exceptionLog($e);
    }
```

the exceptionLog like this

```
private function exceptionLog($e){
    $this->outLogTo('channel_name', $e);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where the `outLogTo` method is called?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I have add the place where is called.

Comment: Is your code mispelled like `$this->execptionLog` or is that a type writing the question here?

Comment: Thanks for point that,just a misspell. I will fix it. And
$this->exceptionLog($e);
also use the outLogto method.

Comment: If an exception is thrown, it will never call `$this->resultLog($result)`.

Comment: Yes,it's true. However,this maybe not the core problem.